# Trying to execute 'a.out' returns "-bash: a.out: command not found."

Tags: c, software-compilation

I wrote a simple C program on a different Linux computer. I would compile it using

```
gcc guess.c
```

That would output an `a.out` file. I would then just type the command `a.out`, and my C program would run.

I attempted to run the same C program on my Pi. It compiles well and outputs an `a.out` file. Though when I attempt to run the command "a.out", I get an error:

> -bash: a.out: command not found.

Does anyone know how to get `a.out` support working on the Pi?

Comment: I would also add the flag "-Wall" to your gcc command, to display all warning messages.

Comment: This could be considered PI related as the OP has observed different behavior on their PI than from previous non-PI experience.  Granted, the answer to the question is a pure UNIX/Linux answer, but many PI questions/issues are UNIX/Linux related.

Comment: "Basically, if you're question is about the Raspberry Pi or about something that happens on the Raspberry Pi you are in the right place."

Direct quote from the help center as to what is on topic.

Comment: @MorganK It's arguable. But we feel that currently it's directed more toward usage of bash usage, and thus is a generic Linux question, as your issue will occur on any Linux system, rather than just on the Raspberry Pi. Please come to [chat] if you wish to discus further!

Comment: @MorganK I'm not mad, but what is the reasoning for you accepting the answer you did over mine? It's perfectly fine that you did, I'm just wondering how to improve answers in the future so they are accepted.

Comment: They are both answers that answered my question. If I could accept two answers I would. It more boiled down to me having to choose one and the other answer was posted first. I liked your thorough explanation if it.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

you should type:

```
./a.out
```

if your file is in the current directory.

also, you might check if executable bit is set with

```
ls -al a.out
```

and if not, set it using

```
chmod +x a.out
```

however, most compilers will set executable bit for you automagically.

Comment: It is also worth to mention that you can not execute the binary if the binary is not compiled for the specific platform(arm).

Comment: The file command will report the details of an executable file, including ARM vs x86.

Answer (score 16):

[You need to put a `./` in front of `a.out` in order to execute that:](https://askubuntu.com/questions/320632/why-do-i-need-to-type-before-executing-a-program-in-the-current-directory)

> When you type the name of a program such as `a.out` the system looks
>   for the file in your PATH. On my system, PATH is set to
>
> ```
> /usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games
> ```
>
> Yours is probably similar.  To check, enter `echo $PATH` in  a
>   terminal.
>
> The system looks through these directories in the order given and if
>   it can't find the program produces a `command not found` error.
>
> Prepending the command with `./` effectively says "forget about the
>   PATH, I want you to look only in the current directory".
>
> Similarly you can tell the system to look in only another specific
>   location by prepending the command with a relative or absolute path
>   such as:
>
> `./Debug/hello` : "look for `hello` in the Debug subdirectory of my
>   current directory."
>
> or `/bin/ls` : "look for `ls` in the directory `/bin`"
>
> By default, the current directory is not in the path because it's
>   considered a security risk. See [Why is . not in the path by
>   default?](https://superuser.com/q/156582/207143) on Superuser for why.
>
> It's possible to add the current directory to your PATH, but for the
>   reasons given in the linked question, I would not recommend it.

I'm not sure why the answer said not to change your PATH, since the answer on SuperUser said that this was a "very lame and useless anti-virus measure, and nothing stops you from adding dot to the path yourself."

Comment: Having "." in your PATH means that as you change your current directory, any file in the current directory that has the same name as a command you are used to typing (or mis-typing) will be executed.  It is generally safer to install executable files in known directories in PATH.  Of course, you can always use a path to execute a local file, "./<file>".